# How to implement multiple websockets with dynamic link in redux action?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, websocket, next.js

my task is to get Binance coins websockets data and set it to redux store and then display them on view, but I dont know how to implement seperate payload for each of these websocket data. Here is what Ive tried recently and the problem in it is that the payload changes frequently and also recieves different coin data. How can I implement this correctly?

```
export function Socket() {
  return function (dispatch: Dispatch) {
    for(let i = 0; i < coins.length; i++) {
      const socket = new WebSocket(`wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/${coins[i]}@trade`)
      socket.onmessage = (event: any) => {
        dispatch({
          type: "websocket",
          payload: JSON.parse(event.data),
        });
      }
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: Provide socket an ID, to have reference so when you do process you know which sent what as payload.

Comment: could you explain more or show it in code? cause I didnt understand

Comment: Assuming you want each "coin" server to have its own bank in memory, we'd send the WebSocket's ID (socket.id) through with payload so when we do store this to memory it could be as simple as Data[socket.id].coinValue = newValue; Question wasn't specific enough it sounds though like a handling of different clients?